# Multiple conditions inside np.where()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have various 3d arrays and I want to get the indices of the array where some conditions are satisfied. As an example, to get the indices, I did

```py
import numpy as np
my_index = np.where((myP.x1)>-64.0 & (myP.x1)<-30.0 & (myP.x2)>10.0 & myP.x2<30.0)
```

Here, `myP.x1`, `myP.x2`, etc are 3D arrays. I want the indices where these above conditions are True. I expect an output of a list of indices which I will then supply to other arrays for a different purpose.

But while running this, I get a rather cryptic error saying

> TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

I have no idea what that is for. I just want to get a list of the indices where the conditions are true.... Any help would be appreciated.

TLDR: Want to get indices from an array where multiple conditions are satisfied using `np.where()`.

Comment: Provide reproducible example please, information about various 3d arrays is not enough.

Comment: Try using this:  my_index= np.where(((myP.x1)>-64.0) & ((myP.x1)<-30.0) & ((myP.x2)>10.0) & (myP.x2<30.0))

Comment: `&` operator has higher precendence than `>`, so you need to use brackets.

Comment: @ipj The data files that i am operating on are huge, so i cannot send you the exact data. But i can give u info about them. x1 x2 and x3 are (1024*1536*64) arrays of floats. I want the indices of the numbers that satisfy the conditions in my where() statement

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma Yes that solved the problem!. Thank you!!!

Comment: @PéterLeéh Thank you, yes, that solved it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Rahul Vishwakarma and @PeterLeeh in the comments,

my_index= np.where(((myP.x1)>-64.0) & ((myP.x1)<-30.0) & ((myP.x2)>10.0) & (myP.x2<30.0))

The above statement solved my problem.